# How to uninstall Ubuntu 12.04 LTS dual booting with Windows 7?

Tags: dual-boot, 12.04, uninstall

I need to uninstall Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from my laptop. It's currently dual booting with windows 7. I've searched and found some ways to do this, but all use some kind of a CD to complete the deletion. I have neither the Ubuntu Live CD nor Windows Install CD/Recovery CD. This laptop did not come with one, and I unfortunately have no available storage device to make a recovery CD.

Is there a way to completely uninstall Ubuntu 12.04 LTS dual booting without using any hardware?

If there's no way, then how to uninstall using the least hardware possible? Or easy to find hardware?

I've nothing against Ubuntu. I installed this as a backup/alternative to error-prone Windows 7. However, after a hardware upgrade, including extra RAMs and a new, better CPU, Windows 7 runs smoothly again. Now I'm running low on hard drive space and need the 40 gig or so of space I partitioned for Ubuntu back.

Any help is appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to this website: http://partedmagic.com/doku.php
2. Download the ISO appropriate to your CPU architecture and burn it to a disc.
3. Boot from it.
4. Delete the partition allocated to Ubuntu via GParted.
5. Resize your Windows partition to fill your drive.

BTW If there is still an option to boot into Ubuntu, you will have to boot into your Windows CD that you have and do something, although I am unsure of what - Google is your friend.